# How to run a python script on startup?

Tags: 12.10, scripts, startup

First, I know that this has been asked before. Tried guides, didn't work...

So I have a python script that has a never ending loop. It accesses the internet.

All I want to do is that after I log in or the computer start, this python script is executed in the background until I shut down the computer.

Let's say my script is currently in my home directory named myscript.py

How could I achieve this task in ubuntu 12.10?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: In the answer I linked to above you want to add the following command in the `.desktop` file `Exec=` field to run your script `python /path/to/myscript.py`.

Comment: @Aditya: the one you linked is running scripts at boot, the one I linked is running scripts at login - this is a different thing, I dont think they should be duped.

Answer (score 0):

"Add to Startup" program is available in Ubuntu. You can use the same to achieve this.

Here is an article where I explained how to add a file to start up in details.
http://www.crappy3.com/home/index/make-your-ubuntu-desktop-look-stunning-with-conky